# How can I read the text message from popup window,which is opened on new browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I clicked on some link, the popup window is opened on new browser. I Want to Read text message from popup window. This is not a alert. How i can read the message. Should i used the Java collection?

Comment: have you tried driver.getWindowHandles?

Comment: @SarikaGharage Can you consider showing us your work, research, relevant HTML DOM & the error stack trace for further analysis? Thanks

Comment: String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
  Set<String> WinID2 = driver.getWindowHandles();
  WinID2.remove(currentWindow);
  String[] handlesArray2 = WinID2.toArray(new String   [WinID2.size()]);
  driver.switchTo().window(handlesArray2[0]).close();
   driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
  Thread.sleep(5000);                                                                                                          By using Above code I am able to see the pop up window on new browser. But how can I display the pop window text message on consol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you are able to switch to the required window i. e. newly opened browser window, you can fetch the text from that window by finding WebElement using **tagName** as **body** and then calling **getText()** method on it. Following is an example code to achieve that:

```
Set<String> winHandles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
Iterator<String> itr = winHandles.iterator();

String currentWin = itr.next();
String newBrowserWin = null;
if (itr.hasNext())
    newBrowserWin = itr.next();

String newBrowserWinText;
if (newBrowserWin!=null) {
    driver.switchTo().window(newBrowserWin);

    newBrowserWinText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
}
```

The variable  **newBrowserWinText** will contain the text of newly opened browser window, once you execute above code.

Let me know, whether above code works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch to window method and move your driver focus to the new windows by getting the windows handles. Then get the page source value or text of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Let try with this one

```
// Store the current window handle
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

// Perform the click operation that opens new window

// Switch to new window opened
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
  driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}

// Get the text message from popup window

// Close the new window, if that window no more required
driver.close();
```